# Xcode tableview subtitle

Tags: xcode, tableview, cell, subtitle

I have been searching for a while trying to get help, but without luck :(

I want to set the subtitle in TableViewCells. The subtitles must not be the same in every cell. I have been writing some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cell 1", @"cell 2", nil];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [tableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{ 
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle      reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle 1", @"Subtitle 2", nil;

return cell;
}
```

The problem is in `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle 1", @"Subtitle 2", nil;`

Does anybody know how to set a different subtitle in each cell?

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly the same way you're setting the cell titles.
You can have another array holding the subtitles and get them like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cell 1", @"cell 2", nil];
    // Assuming that you have declared another property named 'tableSubtitles'
    tableSubtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sub1", @"sub2", nil];
}
```

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableSubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: okay thank you ;) Do u know how to edit the subtitles maximum lines? Its because i got a long subtitle and it can not be on one line.. So if u know how to code so the subtitle will be over 2/3 lines? Good luck

Comment: You could use the `numberOfLines` property of the `detailTextLabel` object, but I have not tested it so I don't know of any implications. You can see [that post](http://adf.ly/91637/banner/the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2009/11/multi-line-uitableviewcell-using.html) though and try it yourself.

Comment: Thats worked! :) But now the text is outside the cell :( The site u fund to me says something about i need to change the height of the cells... but i don't know how to do :( Do u know it? or can u find out for me?

Comment: You can can change your cell heights like this:
(Note that this is a `delegate` method)

  `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 88.0; //Or whatever height you need
}`